# WinRT Returning data from a Page

Tags: windows-runtime

I'm working on a WinRT application that for now consists of two pages. While in the first page the user clicks a button that directs him/her to the second page where he makes a choice that needs to be passed back to the calling page. How can I pass data back to the calling page?

Answer (score 0):

Use a ViewModel. Check out [`Mvvm Light`](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) (available on Nuget). Use a two-way binding to set the data in the ViewModel, then when you return to the other page, retrieve the data from the same ViewModel. There are plenty of [guides for using Mvvm on Channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Visual-Studio-Toolbox/Getting-Started-with-MVVM) as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is possibility to navigate between pages with Behaviours SDK (XAML), concretely NavigateToPageAction with Parameter. Some article [here](http://www.timmykokke.com/2013/09/behaviors-sdk/)

You can reference it

```
xmlns:interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
```

And use it in this way

```
<interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click">
        <core:NavigateToPageAction TargetPage="Presentation.Views.ArticleDetailView" Parameter="{Binding Id}"/>
    </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
</interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

This behaviour you can add to control with some event ( in this case Click event ) and Id is sent to second page. In this page you can process this parameter in code behind. It is not so MVVM oriented but you can try. You don't have to use interface INavigateAble, you can use directly your ViewModel.

```
private INavigateTo<int> NavigationViewModel()
{
    return DataContext as INavigateTo<int>;
} 

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var navigationViewModel = NavigationViewModel();
    var parameter = e.Parameter as int?;
    if (navigationViewModel != null && parameter != null)
    {
        navigationViewModel.SetParameter(parameter)
    }
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}
```

But if you want only sent data and not navigate back to your first page, you can pass as parameter e.g. some Action callback method that can be called in the second page to set some value on first page.